# how do I get a windows text winapi c++?

Tags: c++

I am currently making a Win32 DLL project with `WinAPI`, with a User Interface.
I am confused on how I get a textbox's text in C++. Here is what a bit of my code looks like.

```
case Execute:
    char text[256];
    TCHAR TextBuffer[_MAX_PATH];
    LRESULT result = SendMessage(Pointers::ExecuteBar, WM_GETTEXT, 256, LPARAM(text));
    HandleCommands(std::string(text));
    std::string UserInput = (std::string)(char*)TextBuffer;
    if (Enabled)
    {
        HandleCommands(UserInput);
    }
    else
    {
        PushMessage(L"Not Initialized.", RGB(255, 140, 0));
    };
    break;
};
break;
```

that's my case Execute function.

Here's my WinApi Button for Execute.

```
HWND ExecuteButton = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"EXE", (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE),
    340, 380, 60, 20, Pointers::Window, (HMENU)Execute, DllModule, NULL);
```

I need help because whenever I try and type in something it goes to a message that I put in to notify the user if they typed in something wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you need both `text` and `TextBuffer`? You seem to be using `TextBuffer`, but it's going to contain garbage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the text of a window just use the `GetWindowText()` function

- 1st param is the handle to the window you want to copy its text.
- 2nd param is the char that must be previously defined .
- 3rd param is the max number of chars you will copy.

Example:

```
char copy[ ] = " ";
GetWindowText(hWndTextBox, &copy[0], sizeof(copy)-1);
```

Here the 3rd param will give it an unlimited numbers of chars to get copied you can set it to any integer number like 20

Comment: Thanks for who edited the answer for me but i dont know how to make that gray back ground around the code so if anyone could just comment it here so i can use it in the future to make my answers more readable